How to retrieve query/key/values/output parameters of BERT pretrained?
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
layer = 0
attention_block = model.encoder.layer[layer].attention.self

I want to retrieve the parameters (queries, keys, values, attention_output) of attention_block, for each head separately.
For head 0 for example, I have tried
queries = []
for name, mod in model.named_modules(): 
   if name==f'encoder.layer.{layer}.attention.self.query':
       queries.append(next(mod.parameters()))
h = 0  # head number
dim_per_head = 64
Q_0 = queries[0][h * dim_per_head : (h + 1) * dim_per_head, :]  # query matrix of head 0

and same for keys, values and output weights, but I am not sure this is the right way of dividing the tensor queries[0] in slices. Does anyone have more information about parameter implementation in bert_pretrained?
Thank you!

Your approach seems mostly correct. However, in BERT, the attention mechanism typically employs multi-head attention, meaning that the queries, keys, and values for each head are concatenated along the last dimension. CODE_GIST .This code will correctly retrieve the parameters (queries, keys, values, and attention output) of the attention block for each head separately in a BERT model. Make sure you adjust it according to the specific structure of your BERT model.
